# dump works, but store doesn't - pig - where can I find details of the error?

Tags: apache-pig, hcatalog

I'm trying to load apache log, split into fields and save it into hcatalog.

```
apache_log = LOAD 'httpd-www01-access.log.2014-02-09-*' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);

apache_row = FOREACH apache_log GENERATE FLATTEN (
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL
(line,'^"(\\S+)" \\[(\\d{2}\\/\\w+\\/\\d{4}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} \\+\\d{4}]) (\\S+) (\\S+) "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"'))
AS (ip: chararray, datetime: chararray, session_id: chararray, time_of_request:chararray, request: chararray, status: chararray, size: chararray, referer : chararray, cookie: chararray, user_agent: chararray);
```

If i do:

```
a = sample apache_row 0.001;
dump a
```

it works.

but

```
 store apache_row into 'stage.apache_log' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

doesn't.

Error:

```
2014-02-17 08:17:13,812 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2014-02-17 08:17:13,812 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_201402120751_0117 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2014-02-17 08:17:13,812 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2014-02-17 08:17:13,814 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2014-02-17 08:17:13,815 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
1.2.0.1.3.2.0-111       0.11.1.1.3.2.0-111      pig     2014-02-17 08:16:24     2014-02-17 08:17:13     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201402120751_0117   apache_log,apache_row   MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed! Error - # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201402120751_0117_m_000000    stage.atg_apache_log,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://hadoop1:8020/user/pig/httpd-www01-access.log.2014-02-09-*"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "stage.apache_log"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201402120751_0117
```

Where can I fing any details of the problem? 
There is an an information that more details I can find under:
hadoop1:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201402120751_0117
But when job is finished it doesn't work...

Regards
Pawel

Comment: Write a unit test with PigUnit and see if it works there. You can step through the code with a debugger and find out the detailed error.

Comment: Note that your script uses `sample`. Therefore you will not be executing on the same data in the two test runs, so there's not necessarily any difference between `DUMP` and `STORE` here.  (Also, it means testing with PigUnit is likely to be challenging.) On the job details page, there should be a counter for the number of failed map tasks.  Try to navigate that page to get to the logs of one of the failed task attempts and post that error here.

Comment: The problem is with parsing log file with regexp. Some line doesn't fit the pattern. Interesting, that whole job ends with error. Is it possible to catch the exception and send wrong lines to a file?

Comment: whenever a pig job fails, it creates a log file. This log file is created in the directory from where you executed the pig script. eg /home/user/abc.pig , now suppose your pwd is /home , then you might have executed pig user/abc.pig . so log file is generated inside /home . could you share this log details